# Stop div from bouncing in IOS

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

Hi I have a DIV with the following CSS

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
flex-direction: column;
```

When I touch it and scroll down the parent div, the child div bounces left and right and top and bottom in the parent div. Does anyone know why that happens in Safari on IOS?